# gpg --list-keys is empty but file decrypts bouncycastle encrypted file

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp

I am currently using BouncyCastle PGP in a Java application to read a public key from a string, and encrypt a file using that key. Loading the key...

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
InputStream keyIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(publicKey.getBytes());
PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpKeyRing = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn), new JcaKeyFingerpringCalculator());
PGPPublicKey = pgpKeyRing.getKeyRings().next().getPublicKey();
```

The output file is able to be decrypted with

```
gpg --decrypt file.gpg
```

even though `gpg --list-keys` and `gpg --list-secret-keys` is empty

How is this possible? Is it reading a keyring from somewhere else possibly? I am on CentOS 7, and I have deleted ~/.gnupg and re-created it.

I have also tried changing the public key I am using to encrypt to, and it still decrypts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my code had an error in it, and was writing out an Ascii armored version of the PGP Compressed file, but not Encrypted. As it would happen, `gpg --decrypt` will decompress this file, even if there are no keys in the keyring, because it never does a check. `gpg --debug-level 9` was useful to figure this out.

Comment: You never showed your encryption code, which would've made this question impossible to answer. Please add the missing code.

Comment: I probably won't get around to posting an appropriate sample code - but this answer should be a clue enough if someone is encountering a file they can "decrypt" but they don't think they should have the key for it

Comment: As a question and answer pair it's pretty good for the reasons you stated, but it would be great to have the code that shows the mistake. But that's your call.